# How to set connection string to DbContext after user has login with Unity container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string, unity-container

I am building an MVC application that connect to diferent databases depending on the user that has log in.

For this i have 3 projects DAL using entity framework(DataBaseFirst) where i have extended the dbcontext so that i can pass the connectionstring like this:

```
  public partial class ARACultivoEntities
{
    public ARACultivoEntities(string nameOfConnectionString)
        : base(nameOfConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

**Note: I have the connections strings defined in the web.config of the mvc project.**

There is also another project, Services where i have a genericService from where other service can inherit this like this:

```
 public class GenericService<T> : IGenericService<T>
    where T : class
{

    protected ARACultivoEntities Db;


    protected DbSet<T> Table;



    public GenericService(string nameConnectionString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameConnectionString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("nameConnectionString");
        }

        Db = new ARACultivoEntities(nameConnectionString);
        Table = Db.Set<T>();
    }
```

Now i save the name of the connection string in the user claims when he logs in and in the controllers i have something like this:

```
 public class DeduccionController : Controller
{

    private IGenericService<Deducciones> service;

    public DeduccionController()
    {
        service = ServiceFactoryGeneric<Deducciones>.InitGenericService(GetClaimsUser.Cadena);
        //GetClaimsUser.Cadena has the name of the connectionString
        //ServiceFactoryGeneric<Deducciones>.InitGenericService do this:
        // return new GenericService<T>(connectionString);
    }
```

now i want to instead of having my own factories i want to use an Ioc Container and i have chosen unity for this, i am new to this, i've read some articles and i think i undsertand the basics but i dont know how to pass the connection string after the user has log in because my RegisterTypes hapen at the application start

```
 public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // this happen at application start
        // string nameOfConnectionString = *user is still not loged in*
        container.RegisterType<IGenericService<T>, GenericService<T>>(
              new InjectionConstructor(nameOfConnectionString));
    }
```

i been thinkin to try to tweet the code to register my types after the user has loged in but i dont think this a good idea..

i also have been thinking about adding a public method to my IGenericService so that i can set my connectionString after the service is constructed and implemented something like this:

```
public void SetConnectionString(string nameOfConnectionString)
{ 
   Db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = nameOfConnectionString;
   //not sure if this actually works
}
```

then my controller will be something like this:

```
  public class DeduccionController : Controller
{

    private IGenericService<Deducciones> _service;

    public DeduccionController(IGenericService<Deducciones> service)
    {
        _service = service;
        _service.SetConnectionString(GetUserClaims.Cadena);
    }
```

and let my RegisterTypes just with the:

```
container.RegisterType<IGenericService<T>, GenericService<T>>()
```

but since i new to this world of IoCs i am not sure if this is the best way

What would be the correct way to do this using Unity?
Thank you for reading.
I am sorry for my english not my first languague.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do something similar by swapping connection strings based on a route parameter specifying a geo-location.

I would recommend building your own Unity LifetimeManager that acts in a instance per session scope. Register an object that acts as a configuration container for the connection string property.

[See Unity Lifetime Manager: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.lifetimemanager(v=pandp.30).aspx]

Then you could inject that singleton instance of this configuration object into your controller and set the connection string property once a user has logged in. You could then inject that same singleton instance into a DbContext factory that instantiates your DbContext using the connection string specified in your configuration object.

Like I said, it may not be the most elegant solution, but I liked it better than having to pass a connection string through the many tiers of your application stack. Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be a helpful link for implementing your own session lifetime manager: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707138/using-asp-net-session-for-lifetime-management-unity

Comment: ok, i think i understand the idea, still not sure how i have to implemented, i am going to do some reading about this lifetime manager and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I don't necessarily think my answer is the only answer. I'm sure there many valid ways to sheer this sheep. Keep us updated on your progress.